# Hook to see when a VS web application finishes starting

Tags: visual-studio, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing a Visual Studio Extension (as [a VS Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package(v=vs.120).aspx)) and I'm trying to measure the time from when the user clicks to start the web application to the time a new tab is opened in the web browser and it's ready to use.

Ideally I want to measure the time-to-start when the web application is started with both:

- Debug → Start Debugging (F5)
- Debug → Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5)

Using [IVsUpdateSolutionEvents4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsupdatesolutionevents4.aspx) I can see when the user starts and finishes a:

- Build Solution (`SBF_OPERATION_BUILD`)
- Rebuild Solution (`SBF_OPERATION_BUILD | SBF_OPERATION_FORCE_UPDATE`)
- Clean Solution (`SBF_OPERATION_CLEAN`)

And using [IVsDebuggerEvents.OnModeChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdebuggerevents.onmodechange.aspx) I can see when:

- The user clicks *Debug → Start Debugging* (`DBGMODE_Run`)
- The user clicks *Stop Debugging* (`DBGMODE_Design`)

However, I haven't found a good hook to see when the application has finished starting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't expect that a "magic hook" would be available. In case of web applications here is what I think VS does:

- User hits "Debug"
- VS deploys the package in a temporary location
- VS creates a [WebBrowserInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivswebbrowsingservice.createwebbrowser(v=vs.108))
- VS sends the URL to the browser and fires navigation

At this point VS has pretty much done its job but there's a lot to follow.

- Browser sends the request to the webserver
- Web server loads the application
- Web server sends the response to the browser.

So the browser is the guy to know that the user can start using the app and he must be responsible for firing that event you are looking for.

This is difficult to get as the programmer can pick as default browser Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc.

My opinion is that you need to monitor IIS activity and detect a pattern for what happens when you start a new webapp.

Comment: I figured as much, but thank you! The way your answer lays out all the conceptual steps has taught me many things. Perhaps all I need to do is figure out what URL the project will launch and then monitor the IISExpress logs for that URL.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to see when VS sends the URL to the browser and what URL it's sending?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But if you log the time when you clicked debug, then analyze the IISExpress log, there is 99% chance that the first  request after the "debug hit time" contains the url you want.

Comment: I found also this interface that might help you when the deploy has finished: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdeploystatuscallback(v=vs.108)

Comment: Good point about the logs. Thanks for the interface link, that should be useful.

Comment: You could try this interface to get the URL from the project properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage(v=vs.108)

Comment: It took me a couple months to get to it, but [I finally implemented the approach you suggested](https://github.com/mkropat/VSPerformanceTracker) and it actually works! Thanks again for your help.